# rank of unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, unitary-matrices

Let $U:=[u_1,\cdots,u_n] \in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ with $u_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ be a unitary matrix. Why is $u_j u_j^H$ a rank one matrix for $j=1,\cdots,n$?

($u_j^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose)

Comment: If you have any vector $v$ then $u_ju_j^Hv=u_j(u_j^Hv)$ is just a scalar multiple of $u_j$, hence the image of $v\mapsto u_ju_j^Hv$ is at most one-dimensional (since your matrix is unitary we have $u_j\ne0$ so the image has dimension 1)

Comment: Each row of $u_ju_j^H$ is a constant multiple of $u_j^H\ne O$. Thus there is only one LI row.